# Как сделать war файл в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, maven, war

Опишите подробно шаги пожалуйста, просто пустой проект, от начала(создания) до деплоя!

Comment: http://www.apache-maven.ru/webapp.html

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, много перерыл - а тут так просто)Благодарю )))